# how does usatoday display URI for news docs?

Tags: ajax, web-applications

I am developing a web app/message board in AJAX. Ive come to the part where I need to decide how to display threads.

Should I refresh a completely new page for each thread? Or load it via AJAX. Obviously, I want each thread to be crawlable, linkable, and saveable as a favorite in your browser.

Then I saw USAToday's website (www.usatoday.com/news). Its very interesting how they load the page through a popup window, change the URI, and keep the data in the background.

This is exactly what I want, but I don't know what they are doing.

Can anyone else decipher this or lead me down the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impeccable googling skills has led me to believe that the answer lies in pushState.

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate

Essentially, it appears they are...

1. using the HREF of the provided link to change the URI via pushState.
2. using AJAX to load the contents of the page accessed via the link.
3. on close, they most likely use data from the newly loaded page to figure out what section its was under(sports, entertainment, etc), and reload that page.